# Why are there duplicate lines in WinDbg verbose output?

Tags: windbg

I am trying to understand the verbose output better and am curious why there are duplicate lines when `!sym noisy` is ON. Some lines are totally duplicate others differ very slightly.

In below I have added my comments with prefix <<.

```
0:000> .reload /f app.exe
SYMSRV:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\sym\App.pdb\C214CCE3158A4E2896C82B1F76F690591\App.pdb - file not found
SYMSRV:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\sym\App.pdb\C214CCE3158A4E2896C82B1F76F690591\App.pdb not found << this one doesn't have the file in message, what does that mean?
SYMSRV:  Get File Path: /download/symbols/App.pdb/C214CCE3158A4E2896C82B1F76F690591/App.pdb

SYMSRV:  Notifies the client application that a proxy has been detected.
SYMSRV:  Connecting to the Server: https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.
SYMSRV:  Successfully connected to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Sending the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully sent the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Waiting for the server to respond to a request.

SYMSRV:  Successfully received a response from the server.
*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  Closing the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully closed the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Notifies the client application that a proxy has been detected.
SYMSRV:  Connecting to the Server: https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.
SYMSRV:  Successfully connected to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Sending the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully sent the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Waiting for the server to respond to a request.

SYMSRV:  Successfully received a response from the server.
*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  Closing the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully closed the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Get File Path: /download/symbols/App.pdb/C214CCE3158A4E2896C82B1F76F690591/file.ptr

SYMSRV:  Notifies the client application that a proxy has been detected.
SYMSRV:  Connecting to the Server: https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.
SYMSRV:  Successfully connected to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Sending the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully sent the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Waiting for the server to respond to a request.

SYMSRV:  Successfully received a response from the server.
*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  Closing the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully closed the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\sym\App.pdb\C214CCE3158A4E2896C82B1F76F690591\App.pdb - file not found
SYMSRV:  https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/App.pdb/C214CCE3158A4E2896C82B1F76F690591/App.pdb not found << 'file' is missing
SYMSRV:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\sym\App.pdb\C214CCE3158A4E2896C82B1F76F690591\App.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\sym\App.pdb\FF12D89B77D742CAB1CB145EC85C2ABD1\App.pdb - file not found << extra 'file' is there
SYMSRV:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\sym\App.pdb\FF12D89B77D742CAB1CB145EC85C2ABD1\App.pdb - file not found << duplicate to the previous line
DBGHELP: c:\test\app\pdb\App.pdb cached to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\sym\App.pdb\FF12D89B77D742CAB1CB145EC85C2ABD1\App.pdb
DBGHELP: c:\test\app\pdb\App.pdb cached to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\sym\App.pdb\FF12D89B77D742CAB1CB145EC85C2ABD1\App.pdb << exact copy
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\sym\App.pdb\FF12D89B77D742CAB1CB145EC85C2ABD1\App.pdb - mismatched pdb
DBGHELP: c:\test\app\pdb\exe\App.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\test\app\pdb\symbols\exe\App.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: C:\Test\App\App.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\users\username\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\App\Release\App.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: Couldn't load mismatched pdb for C:\Test\App\App.exe
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for App.exe
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for App.exe
DBGHELP: App - no symbols loaded

************* Symbol Loading Error Summary **************
Module name            Error
App                    PDB not found : cache*
                Unable to locate the .pdb file in this location

                       The system cannot find the file specified : SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
                The SYMSRV client failed to find a file in the UNC store, or there
                is an invalid UNC store (an invalid path or the pingme.txt file is
                not present in the root directory), or the file is present in the
                symbol server exclusion list.

                       PDB not found : c:\test\app\pdb\symbols\exe\App.pdb
                Unable to locate the .pdb file in this location
```

Comment: I never get `SYMSRV ... - file not found` I only get `DBGHELP ... - file not found` Which version of WinDbg and which version of dbghelp.dll are you using?

Comment: I upvoted this question because it happened to me once and I still have no idea why. The windbg tag is popular with me. I take a look at every few days or a week. :)

Comment: @conio: I'd expect you could disassemble DbgHelp and tell us why it's the case... ;-)

Comment: Please check if you have multiple symbol paths set through .sympath command.